# How to restrict the mouse cursor inside the window

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I'm creating a simple Windows window based app. The app consists of the main window and the small `POPUP` style window. How can i make the mouse cursor to stay "trapped"/restricted inside that `POPUP` window until the user clicks inside the `POPUP` itself. I've tried to use the `ClipCursor` function but that only initially positions the cursor inside the POPUP when the window is "spawned", but then I can easily move the cursor outside the window through all the screen.

Comment: `ClipCursor` is the correct API to use. If it isn't working for you then there is probably an issue with your code. We cannot see your code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: WinAPI reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-cursors